# Enzyme check checkbox status

Tags: testing, reactjs, enzyme

I have following example component

```
export default class Header extends Component{

render(){
  let activeStyle   = {"backgroundColor": "green"};
  let inActiveStyle = {"backgroundColor": "red"};
  return(
    <div className="profile-header" style={(this.props.active)?
      activeStyle:inActiveStyle}>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.active} readOnly/>
  </div>
 );
}
}
```

Using Enzyme and chai I would like to assert, that for

```
this.props.active = true
```

The backgroundColor is green and the checkbox is checked.

Here's my test case

```
describe('<Header />', () => {
  it('valid component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ProfileHeader
    active= {true}
    />);
   ????
});
```

But how can I assert both cases?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check the below solution, for the background color you can check with the css string selector (may need some changes in the selector).
All the below assertions are tested and working.

```
describe('<Header />', () => {
  it('valid component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ProfileHeader />);
    wrapper.setProps({ active: true });
    let checkbox = wrapper.find({ type: 'checkbox' });
    expect(checkbox.props().checked).to.equal(true);
    expect(wrapper.find('.backgroundColor')).to.equal('green');
    wrapper.setProps({ active: false });
    checkbox = wrapper.find({ type: 'checkbox' });
    expect(checkbox.props().checked).to.equal(false);
    expect(wrapper.find('.backgroundColor')).to.equal('red');
  });
});
```